# How can we specify the return type of a SOAP webservice as JSON format?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, webmethod

This is my method that return xml format but i need to return Json type format.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetAllCity(long UID, string IMEINo)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ExeWeb2 cd = new ExeWeb2();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //booking
    string qyr = "";
    // self booking

    ds = cd.retData("select city_name from city order by city_name");
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    ds1.Tables.Add(dt.Copy());
    ds1.Tables[0].TableName = "City";


    System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    ds1.WriteXml(s, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  DataTable dt11 = ds1.Tables[0];

    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();


    Dictionary<string, object> row;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt11.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt11.Columns)
        {
           row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
       }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```